# What's goin on with the right front wheel of my van?

Tags: ford, brakes, noise, wheels, wheel-bearing

I was drivin yesterday and all sudden a sound happened that I didn't like.

It was kindof like brake noise... a light squeek... but also kinda like that slippin belt sound like when people start their cars up that dont take care of em good.

It sounds kinda like a teapot goin off... like basically the same tone regardless of how fast yer goin.  It's constant in nature generally... when it's happenin.

I pulled over and stuck my head under the vehicle hopin to find a tree branch stuck in the brake calper or sum.  You know when that happens and a twig segment gets to restin just right on the rotor so it starts singin?  It sounds exactly how that would sound.

But now I'm scared, cuz there was no dang branch.  There was nothin I could see at all other than normal van parts.

To me it dont sound like a bearing... cuz it sounds kinda squeeky like rubber-on-rubber almost... it's confusing... not grindy like metal on metal (and I have bad bearings happen before... I even had one get so hot the axle had to had to be sawed off by the dealership n order to remove it)

So I guess we could make it fun like a riddle:

- I sound wierd (I splained it above)
- I sound like I'm comin from the front right
- I never happen when the vehicle is stopped
- I does change sometimes when brakes are applied (gets more quiet or stops while brakes are pushed on)
- I sometimes go away but then get woke up again by goin over some bumps
- I definitely change with regards to how much lateral force is applied to the front wheels such as weavin in the road or bein on a tilted road one way or the other.  I'm "on" when turning left or leanin right, and "off" when turnin right or leanin left.
- I am either on or off, there is no in between.
- I ain't no different whether the van is in neutral or not, only matters if the van is moving or not.
- I am part of a 1998 Ford 5.4 v8 econoline van.

What am I? and what's goin on?

Comment: "*WHat am I?*"  You are -  taxing my ability to understand what language you are speaking.

Comment: I get the feeling this just a series of blog posts far removed from reality.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to say that I appreciate y'all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll be god dang!

I am over the moon right now y'all.

Y'all aint gown believe this but I done took a second look at that there right front rotor area and found this lil sucker right up in there:

[image]
[image]

I just cant believe I actually had this dun diagnosed in my own head to the T!!!!

It WAS a dang leaf!  I knowed it!

I hope this helps someone else who gets this same noise.

Answer (score 1):

Is there's no foreign object debris in the wheel then a noise from a front wheel comes from a limited set of sources in a rear wheel drive car/van:

1. Wheel bearing: Not all wheel bearing failures sound the same
2. Suspension: you can get squeaks and rattles under movement if there's a bad suspension component
3. Brake system: a loose caliper, failed caliper, seized caliper and other things can cause noise from a wheel. It could also be a brake wear sensor, which means your pads need replacing

So, there's no way to say for sure, take it apart and do a thorough inspection.